# Debo agregar al Where las condiciones del Case del Select?

Tags: sql, select, optimización, db2

tengo la siguiente sentencia, mi duda es: si quiero optimizar el tiempo de respuesta, debo a agregar al Where las condiciones del Case? el campo de ordenamiento de mi tabla es Cedula y hay tipos de productos que o me interesan, mi duda es si es mejor dejar el el Case lo descarte o desde el Where? porque el campo Tipo no es clave en mi tabla gracias

**Sentencia Actual**

```
Select                                  
Max(Case When Tipo In('S','D')        
Then 'S' Else 'N' End) Comestibles,       
Max(Case When Tipo In('M','V','K')    
Then 'S' Else 'N' End) Aseo,        
Max(Case When Tipo='L'                
Then 'S' Else 'N' End) Entretenimiento,       
From Productos
Where Cedula = 123456789 and Estado ='A'
```

o la sentencia debe ser????

```
Select                                  
Max(Case When Tipo In('S','D')        
Then 'S' Else 'N' End) Comestibles,       
Max(Case When Tipo In('M','V','K')    
Then 'S' Else 'N' End) Aseo,        
Max(Case When Tipo='L'                
Then 'S' Else 'N' End) Entretenimiento,       
From Productos
Where Cedula = 123456789 and Estado ='A' And
Tipo In('S','D','M','V','K','L')
```

**Produtos**

```
Tipo   Descripcion  Estado Cedula

S      Arroz         A     12345  
D      Carne         I     12345
M      Jabón         A     12345
L      Ipad          A     12345   
Z      Otro          A     12345
W      Otro          A     12345
```

**Resultado**

```
Comestibles Aseo Entretenimiento
    S        S         S
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cual seria el punto de tener en un where algo que va a traer igual todos los registros?

Comment: Hola, en mi tabla hay registros que no me interesan, como los Tipo Z o W, pero debo descartar esos registros en el Where? mira que mis Case no es para los Z o W

Comment: No entiendo mucho la idea de todo este select. Pero si, si no los vas a usar, no deberias traerlos.. mas si tenes un indice por ese campo.

Comment: Mi indice es por el campo cedula, no por el campo Tipo, la idea de mi Select es que me muestre que tipos de productos tiene el cliente más no los productos, solo Saber con S o N si tiene el producto

Comment: Si la cantidad de registros que trae es poca (o sea no son millones), no ganarias nada agregando ese where. Ya que vas a recorrerlos todos igual.

Comment: Son 60 millones de registros

Comment: Para cada cedula? recorda que con eso, ya acortaste la cantidad...